# Prevent a rollback of an inserted record due to an exception

Tags: lightning-web-components, exception, rollback, unhandled-exception

I have a LWC component which calls an apex class that does callout:

```
public static List<Case> doCallout(List<Case> cases) {
    .......
    CalloutLogger.insertLog(req, res, time);
    ........
    try {
         ....
         if(isFromComponent) throwAuraException(System.Label.CustomException);
         ....
     } catch(Exception e) {
         ....
     }
}
```

The `throwAuraException` method:

```
private static void throwAuraException(String message) {
     AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(message);
     e.setMessage(message);
     throw e;
}
```

On LWC:

```
handleSend() {
     sendRequest({caseToSend : this.recordId})
     .catch(error => {
      ......
     }).then(result => {
      ......
     });
}
```

Inside the CalloutLogger.insertLog(req, res, time); method I am inserting a record of Logger__c. The problem is that when `throwAuraException` method is called the logger record inserted gets rolledback, due to throwing an exception that is not handled in the Apex code. But the exception is caught in the catch of LWC.

I would like to insert the logger record even if the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is oversimplified (the Apex appears to never throw an exception, thus would always insert the log record), but in general, there are two ways to go about this.

First, you can create a Platform Event with "Publish Immediately" enabled, then call EventBus.publish, with a trigger or Flow on a Platform Event to log the record asynchronously.

```
try {
  doStuff();
} catch(Exception e) {
  EventBus.publish(createLogEvent(e.getMessage()));
  throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
}
```

---

Second, the method I typically use, is to call another apex function in your catch for which the sole purpose is to log an error.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false) public static void logError(String error) {
  insert new Log__c(Message__c=error);
}
```

...

```
try {
  let result = await apexMethod1(params);
} catch(e) {
  await logError(e.message);
}
```

(or...)

```
 apexMethod1(params)
.then(
   result => { ... }
 )
 .catch(
   error => { logError(error.message); }
 );
```